# Always getting "status":false while using rest api in codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-restserver, codeigniter-restapi

I am using [Ashimante Rest Server API](https://github.com/atishamte/rest-server-codeigniter-2.2.x) in my project.

This is what I did:-

1. I have put the Rest.php controller in the **application/libraries**
   folder
2. I have created **webservice-v1** folder inside the
   **application/controllers/** folder i.e. **application/controllers/webservice-v1**
3. I have Controller files **rest_api_common.php** and
   **webservice_test.php** inside the webservice-v1 folder.

This is my `rest_api_common.php` code:-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/Rest.php');
class Rest_api_common extends REST {

    // some variable declarations //

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // loading models and custom config files// 
    }
}
```

I want the variables and functions available to all the webservice functions. So my webservice_test.php file code goes like this:-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
include('rest_api_common.php');
class Webservice_test extends Rest_api_common
{
    function  __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function mongodata_post()
    {
        $this->response(array(),200);
    }
}
```

I have defined route like this:-

```
$route['rest-api/v1/mongodata'] = "webservice-v1/webservice_test/mongodata_post";
```

Using postman app, I am calling the API like this using POST method:-

```
http://testdomain.com/rest-api/v1/mongodata
```

I am getting this response:-

```
{"status":false,"error":false}
```

What am I doing wrong?